# how to use trim in fetch url

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

how to retrieve the verif code, here I try to do the next regex using trim but an error message appears "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')"

and I just want to fetch the verification code, like in the image

```
my code 
const checkInboxUrl = 'https://getnada.com/api/v1/inboxes/';
const getMessageUrl = 'https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/';
const refreshMailboxUrl = 'https://getnada.com/api/v1/u/';

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

class Getnada {
  constructor() {
    this.email = '';
    this.verificationCode = '';

  }

  async getEmail(email = 'urmxhbwrz@getnada.com') {
      this.email = email;
    return this;
  }

  async getMailbox(pattern, sleepTime = 5000) {
    await sleep(sleepTime);
    const timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    const refreshMailboxResponse = await fetch(refreshMailboxUrl + this.email + '/' + timestamp);
    const checkInboxResponse = await fetch(checkInboxUrl + this.email);
    const checkInboxJson = await checkInboxResponse.json();
    const getMessageResponse = await fetch(getMessageUrl + checkInboxJson.msgs[0].uid);
    const readInbox = await getMessageResponse.text();
    const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    const verificationCodeMatch = regex.exec(readInbox);
    this.verificationCode = verificationCodeMatch[1].trim();
    console.log(verificationCodeMatch)
    return this;
  }
  
}
const getnada = new Getnada();
async function main() {
  console.log((await getnada.getEmail()))
  console.log((await getnada.getMailbox()))
}
main();
```

[image]

https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/8lra5CwOQcHvja3mpQZgO7G5RPTS3W

Comment: You are not passing any pattern to `getMailbox ` call

Comment: sorry I don't know how @Fcmam5

Comment: You have to add something to your function call: `console.log((await getnada.getMailbox(SOMETHING)))` And that `SOMETHING` is what you want to parse from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the verification code, you can try to change this lines :

```
const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
const verificationCodeMatch = regex.exec(readInbox);
this.verificationCode = verificationCodeMatch[1].trim();
```

to :

```
const verificationCodeMatch = pattern.exec(readInbox);
this.verificationCode = verificationCodeMatch[0].trim();
```

---

And change this line too :

```
console.log((await getnada.getMailbox()))
```

to :

```
console.log((await getnada.getMailbox(/\b\d{6,6}\b/)));
```

---

This regex `/\b\d{6,6}\b/` will filter out strings containing exactly 6 digits of numbers which is the verification code.